# Modifying a particular line in a text file from the command-line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, command-line

I have a text file "text.txt", it contains a bunch of lines with text (or empty lines).

I am trying to form a single sed/awk command-line command that will let me comment out any like (by adding a "#" to the start of whatever line number I specify).

For example, the text file might look like:

`A
B
C
D`
and I want to issue a command that specifies line number 2, so it will look like:

`A
#B
C
D`

If it's possible to specify a range of lines, so multiple lines could be modified, like "2-4" or 2,3,4" that would help, too.

I've found conflicting (to me) information about the -n and -e options in sed, and just can't quite get it to work as I hoped. I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

I've been stringing concepts together that I found in other questions, like having to keep the line, but add "#" to the start of it, so I've got "s/(.*)/#$1/" as the back substitution.

I thought it might work as:
`sed '2,4!s/(.)/#$1/' text.txt` 
However, I get `s/.: Event not found.`
This seemed to have some good parts to it, however, it didn't quite work as I hoped, and it only deals with one line, not all lines `cat text.txt | sed -n '2{s/(.)/#$1/;p}'`

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Why are you negating the address?  If you want to add a # at the beginning of lines 2 thru 4, just do `sed -e '2,4s/^/#/'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple `sed` substitute will also work given the line number, e.g.

```
sed -i '2s/^/# /' file
```

The above will edit `file` in place commenting line 2 inserting `"# "` at the beginning of the line. To pass in the line number as an argument, *double-quote* the expression, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i "$1s/^/# /" "$2"
```

Will take the line number as the first argument and the file to comment as the second and edit the file in-place making the comment. You should validate the first argument is an integer and that the second is a file that exists and is non-empty. If you save the script as `cmt` and make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x cmt`), then you would comment the 2nd line in `file` as:

```
./cmt 2 file
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 6):

This should be a task for `awk`. In this solution creating a variable names `lines` which will having line numbers in it whichever you want to change(comma separated), just mention any number of line numbers with comma separated values in it and that should do the trick here. Tested it successfully on https://ideone.com/ajnNSU

```
awk -v lines="2,3,4" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(lines,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    linechange[array[i]]
  }
}
FNR in linechange{
  $0="#" $0
}
1
' Input_file
```